# need to count only numbers after underscore symbol in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2007

I need to check if numbers are there after underscore symbol and put that numbers count as shown below.

[image: aff_ua_affli_key_cm_12548210 aff_ua_affli_key_cm_\d{8} aff_ua_affli_key_cm_125211 aff_ua_affli_key_cm_\d{6} aff_ua_affli_key_cm_1254212 aff_ua_affli_key_cm_\d{7}]

I am very new to excel, please how to write a formula for this.
Thank you so much in advance

Comment: Are the characters before the number always "cm_" ?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it shows no effort to research the problem or attempt to solve it. Suggest you read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Can you please read about [the problems with images images of text](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11107541) and then [edit] to convert your images of tables into markup tables? See [/editing-help#tables](/editing-help#tables) for how. You might find [tablesgenerator.com](//www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables) useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps you can try something like this. Not sure about your Excel Version.

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `B1`

```
=REPLACE(A1,FIND("@",SUBSTITUTE(A1,"_","@",5)),255,
"_\d{"&LEN(-LOOKUP(0,-RIGHT(A1,ROW($ZY$1:INDEX($Z:$Z,LEN(A1))))))&"}")
```

---

If you have access to `MS365` then you could try as below,

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `C1`

```
=LET(x,TEXTSPLIT(A1,"_"),
c,LEN(TAKE(x,,-1)),
TEXTJOIN("_",,DROP(x,,-1),"\d{"&c&"}"))
```

---

I tried made it short in `MS365` version

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `D1`

```
=TEXTBEFORE(A1,"_",-1)&"_\d{"&LEN(TAKE(TEXTSPLIT(A1,"_"),,-1))&"}"
```

---

With One Spill Array Formula.

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `D1`

```
=MAP(A1:A3,LAMBDA(m,
TEXTBEFORE(m,"_",-1)&"_\d{"&LEN(TAKE(TEXTSPLIT(m,"_"),,-1))&"}"))
```

---

Comment: Thank you Bhattacharya, can you please help me one more condition what the row is like this "aff_ua_affli_key_cm_128218_cdf_125" and need aff_ua_affli_key_cm_\d{6}_cdf_\d{3}

Comment: I think that is different question sir, it was not mentioned earlier, still give me sometime, and i need to know your excel version as well and is it possible there will be another numbers after those two

Comment: Thank you sir, Excel is 2017 version and extention is .xlsx

Comment: Sorry I have not heard about Excel 2017

Comment: sorry, Version is Microsoft® Excel® for Microsoft 365 MSO (Version 2210 Build 16.0.15726.20188) 64-bit

Comment: Please show few more samples. One is not fine. there can be cm and cdf so we need to see few more, if that possible

Comment: aff_ua_affli_key_cm_128218_cdf_125 -- > aff_ua_affli_key_cm_\d{6}_cdf_\d{3}
aff_ua_affli_key_Culmn_458918_Xdef_125_ref_2589 --> aff_ua_affli_key_Culmn_\d{6}_Xdef_\d{3}_ref_\d{4}

Comment: @KBS I have no knowledge about `Regex`, all this will be easy with that. with formula it cant be a definitive one I believe. I will give a try with formulas.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251287/discussion-between-kbs-and-mayukh-bhattacharya).

Answer (score 0):

I make the assumption that the characters "cm_" are always before the number:

```
=len(mid(A1,find("cm_",A1,1)+3,30))
```

The len() counts the number of characters,

mid() gets the numbers occurring after the text defined in find()

Then:

LEFT(A1,FIND("cm_",A1,1)+2)&"\d{"&LEN(MID(A1,FIND("cm_",A1,1)+3,30))&"}"

Comment: Thanks Mike but
CM_ is not always same, only the condition is after "_" if starts with number then we need to numbers count and set that in flower bracket  \d{ }

Comment: My second version shows the result added in the curly brackets.

Answer (score 0):

My output is here in cell **D2**..

[image: Result]

=REPLACE(C2,MATCH(TRUE,ISNUMBER(--MID(C2,SEQUENCE(LEN(C2)),1)),0),LEN(C2),"\d{"&SUMPRODUCT((ISNUMBER(--MID(C2,SEQUENCE(LEN(C2)),1))*1))&"}")

if your excel doesn't support for Sequence function then you can use ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(C2)) instead..